# Is there a way to get changes.list with a maxResults limit in reverse chronological order?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm interested in seeing recent changes, though if you specify a cap, you get the oldest changes first.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `startChangeId` query parameter if you want to get only a subset of the most recent changes: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes/list

Comment: startChangeId is somewhat suboptimal for my needs, as I need to make multiple calls to potentially get a startChangeId, and also maintain some state on my side.

This is what I am currently doing, but I'm just wondering if there is a cleaner way I can just do a query for last N changes without an application having to maintain state.

Comment: Hey Claudio, is it possible to share with us what APIs / parameters the "Recent" and "Activity" feeds in Drive use ?

They seem to do exactly what I am interested in.